# Generate PDF report based on the data contained in GWT DataGrid

Tags: gwt, pdf

with `GWT 2.4`, i'm developing a web ordering system wherein user can select items and put it in the cart then check it out after providing the quantity of each item. then, when user clicks PDF button, a pdf report will be generated based on the items found on the `CellTable` then the open with/save file dialog will appear.

How can do this one with GWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a request containing the data from client to server.
On the server side you handle the request, parse the data and generate the PDF file and then you send the response containing the PDF file and in the header you should set:

```
("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="yourFileName.pdf");
```

Comment: hi Catalin. thanks for the answer. can you show me how to make a request?

Comment: well you will have to read about GWT REQUEST - http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication.html ... and send your data to the server.

Comment: If you use the standard gwt servlet, it can. If you use an external, standard HttpServlet, you can't.

Comment: i haven't. i know how to generate a pdf file. my problem really is how to make that open/save as dialog appear in my browser when the button is clicked. sorry, i don't have any clue. haven't tried doing this before. please help. thanks in advance. appreciate it.

Comment: I won't write the code for you but I can tell you how to do it.   
After you learn how to request from client (the data .. let's say a json string representing your data) and on the server side to generate a pdf using that json string, you will (at least I know I will do this) serialize your file and you will get a byte[], which you will send to the client (this is the response).
If I were you, I would have a check on the net about: GWT req-resp, serialization, building a file from a byte[].
GOOD LUCK!

Comment: well, thanks for all the pointers you've mentioned on how to do it. actually, i want to do it with GWT RPC.

Answer (score 0):

1. when you click on PDF button the `Asyncmethod` call.You have to passed all details in async method to `Serviceimplementaion` class where your method going to implement.
2. After that you can use it itextPdf library for generate PDF.
3. You can use below link for create PDF file.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPDF/article.html